# How to set different margins size in RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and I add an ItemDecoration to specify the margin between each items.
I want the bottom margin to be different if the item is the last in his group. This way, the grid will display very clearly which items will be in which group.

Here is my implementation of the getItemOffsets method in my custom ItemDecoration :

```
    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {

    val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)

    outRect.left = if (isInFirstColumn(position))
        1
    else
        spacingBetweenSR4GR

    outRect.bottom = if (isInLastRow(position))
        1
    else if (isLastItemInEBGroup(position))
        spacingBetweenEBGroup
    else
        spacingBetweenSR4GR

}
```

The problem is that the bottom margin is always the same, even if the tests returns true.